# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. during deployment

Tags: magento2, installation, setup

hope you can help me out!

Best regards

Joost

[2020-03-28 19:24:43] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist at /home/admin/domains/aquariumvissenwinkel.nl/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
[2020-03-28 19:24:44] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist at /home/admin/domains/aquariumvissenwinkel.nl/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
[2020-03-28 19:26:19] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist at /home/admin/domains/aquariumvissenwinkel.nl/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
[2020-03-28 19:26:19] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy does not exist at /home/admin/domains/aquariumvissenwinkel.nl/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the requested class is not compiled and requires to be compiled. Code compilation should fix the issue if that is the case.

You can try running `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and see if the issue is solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the modules -

bin/magento module:enable --all

Then run the following command -

bin/magento setup:di:compile